# Using Nethereum to estimate gas for exactInputSingle function call on UniSwap V3 Router contract

Tags: ethereum, uniswap, nethereum

I'm trying to interact with the UniSwap V3 Router contract via Nethereum but have hit a road block. New to attempting to send transactions and would like some guidance on what I'm doing wrong. Also a little unsure if I need to convert certain parameters to be compatible with the EVM, so any help there would be great!

My first step is to get a gas estimate of the transaction involving a token swap via exactInputSingle on the UniSwap V3 router. However, I'm getting an RPC error: "execution reverted: eth_estimateGas". I couldn't see any specific information in the exception that would help.

From the UniSwap docs, my parameters match what is specified. The parameters expected for exactInputSingle are:

```
struct ExactInputSingleParams {
        address tokenIn;
        address tokenOut;
        uint24 fee;
        address recipient;
        uint256 deadline;
        uint256 amountIn;
        uint256 amountOutMinimum;
        uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96;
    }
```

And my code is:

```
var web3 = new Web3(account, "BSC endpoint");
var routerContract = web3.Eth.GetContract(pcsRouterAbi, pcsRouterAddress);
var exactInputSingleFunction = routerContract.GetFunction("exactInputSingle");
var deadline = UtilityMethods.DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(3));

var parms = new
    {
        tokenIn = "0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955",
        tokenOut = "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c",
        fee = new BigInteger(500),
        recipient = walletBsc.address, //My wallet address
        deadline = new BigInteger(deadline),
        amountIn = new BigInteger(0.2),
        amountOutMinimum = new BigInteger(0),
        sqrtPriceLimitX96 = new BigInteger(0)
    };

//Encode params
var encodedFunctionParams = exactInputSingleFunction.GetData(parms); 
        
//Get gas estimate
var gas = await exactInputSingleFunction.EstimateGasAsync(encodedFunctionParams); //Gives "execution reverted: eth_estimateGas" RPC error
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

1. Generally Ethereum operates on UInt256 values so you don't actually want to pass .2 instead you want to pass .2 * 10**18 (Where 18 is the number of decimals of the token)
2. You need to make sure you call the approve method on the token for the router address first.

First get the ERC-20 ABI and import it.

```
var tokenIn = "0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955"
var routerContract = web3.Eth.GetContract(erc20Abi, tokenIn);
var approveFunction = routerContract.GetFunction("approve");
```

Then you need to pass either the amount you're trying to swap for or the Int256.MaxValue I'll use the exact amount for the example,

**Note:** if you approve max amount you don't have to call approve each time

```
var approveParams = new { spender = pcsRouterAddress, amount = new BigInteger(2000000000000000000)}

var encodedApproveFunctionParams = approveFunction.GetData(approveParams); 

//Then estimate gas and call....
```